# Problem handling threads within a DLL in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, logging, dll

I'm testing out the **QuickLogger** library from *Exilon*, which I found to be a pretty versatile logging library, and later on found that it can be accessed through the *GetIt Package Manager*.

I have been struggling to encapsulate logging abilities for our win32 apps, but only when they are executed on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2. If I run the code on Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016 or 2019, it works like a charm.

The problem seems to be related to thread handling inside a DLL.

I isolated the problem to the bare minimum code.

**The library**

```pascal
library libProject;

{ Important note about DLL memory management: ShareMem must be the
  first unit in your library's USES clause AND your project's (select
  Project-View Source) USES clause if your DLL exports any procedures or
  functions that pass strings as parameters or function results. This
  applies to all strings passed to and from your DLL--even those that
  are nested in records and classes. ShareMem is the interface unit to
  the BORLNDMM.DLL shared memory manager, which must be deployed along
  with your DLL. To avoid using BORLNDMM.DLL, pass string information
  using PChar or ShortString parameters. }

uses
  //ShareMem,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  Quick.Logger,
  Quick.Logger.Provider.Console;

{$R *.res}


function AddIntegers(const _a, _b: integer): integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result := _a + _b;
  Logger.Debug('Some debug info');
end;

exports
  AddIntegers;

begin
  Logger.Providers.Add(GlobalLogConsoleProvider);
  with GlobalLogConsoleProvider do
  begin
    LogLevel := LOG_VERBOSE;
    ShowEventColors := True;
    Enabled := True;
  end;

end.
```

**The test program**

```pascal
program consoleProject;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}


uses
  //ShareMem,
  System.SysUtils,
  Quick.Logger,
  Quick.Logger.Provider.Console;

function AddIntegers(_a, _b: integer): integer; stdcall; external 'libProject.dll';

begin
  Logger.Providers.Add(GlobalLogConsoleProvider);

  try
    WriteLn(AddIntegers(1, 2));
    WriteLn('Press Enter');
    ReadLn;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      WriteLn(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

end.
```

Basically, the problem is that the DLL prevents the app from terminating normally because of some unfinished thread execution.

Comment: Consider calling `.Stop()` yourself when logging/your program should end.

Comment: Why use a DLL? Just put the code in the application.

Comment: @AmigoJack, I tried using stop with no success.

Comment: @fpiette the reason for using a DLL is simply about abstraction, in order to change the logger engine or make some tweak or setting, without having to recompile all the apps.

Comment: Your first port of call is the developer of this library. Submit an issue.

Comment: Why do you think it has anything to do with threads? I see no threads involved here.

Comment: Did you test with file logging instead of the console?

Comment: I already did @DavidHeffernan here https://github.com/exilon/QuickLogger/issues/46 but maybe someone would find a way to see the actual problem, which a I can't really tell. Thanks!!

Comment: @Olivier, the library uses a pretty clever way of combining threads and queues to return handle immediately to the app in order to speed up the UI, and the actual log occurs to multiple providers in a background task. Using Windows SysInternals Process Explorer, shows a thread unfinished with a call to a method inside the DLL. Trying to log to a file leads to the same situation.